# String literal expressions should be on the left side of an equals comparison

Tags: java, sonarqube, pmd

```
!mapData.get("PARTY_ID").equals("")         // <-- gives SonarQube error
```

In the above piece of code, I am getting "String literal expressions should be on the left side of an equals comparison" this error in Sonar. So how we can avoid it.

I tried this:

```
("").equals(!mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID"))
```

But it does not work.
Give some advice......

Comment: Already tried and getting this error "The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) Object"...

Answer (score 40):

Others have pointed out that the way to avoid this error is to use:

```
! ("".equals(mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID")))
```

But no one has pointed out *why* this matters.  The reason the literal should be on the left side of the equals comparison is to avoid the possibility of an exception if the string being compared to it is null.

As written in the question, if the value of `mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID")` was `null`, then  the expression would be trying to invoke the `equals(..)` method of *an object that doesn't exist.* That would throw an exception.  By putting the literal on the left, then even if the value of `mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID")` was `null`, the method `"".equals(...)` would be defined and would not throw an exception.  It would simply return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't surround a blank string with quotes. `("").equals(!mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID"))` should just be 
`! ("".equals(mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID")))`

Comment: Yeah, that's not what the OP intended I don't think

Comment: I tried with this one "".equals(!mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID")) I am getting this error "The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) Object"...

Comment: Use the edited version with !("".equals(mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID"))).

Comment: Yes..I tried with this one--> !("".equals(mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID"))). ...I am not getting any error...

Comment: But I have a doubt whether  !("".equals(mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID"))) and   ("").equals(mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID"))  are same or not...I am little bit confused!!!!!!!!!

Comment: `!("".equals(mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID")))` will be equal to `!mapData.get("PARTY_ID").equals("")`, which is what you originally had.  If I were you, I would read into basic Java syntax a little more, as it seems that you're not very familiar with the language.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin W.'s answer is correct but has an error:

You shouldn't surround a blank string with quotes.

```
  ("").equals(mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID"))
```

should just be

```
  !("".equals(mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID")))
```

The above is correct.

EDIT:

Source: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-224

Comment: I tried with this one  "".equals(!mapData.get("CON_PTY_PARTY_ID")) I am getting this error "The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) Object"...

Comment: *Kevin W.'s answer is correct but has an error* - but both of you propose the same solution! Seems to me that Kevin W. was faster ;-)

Comment: *You shouldn't surround a blank string with quotes.* - ... with parentheses, you mean. Quotes are ok.

Comment: @Thomas his answer was edited after mine was posted.